# Excel duplicate rows to CSV cell formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet such as this: (See Columns A through D of "Formula Output Column E" image - had to remove original 1st image due to not enough reputation points)

And would like to make a formula to consolidate it so that when the first three columns are duplicates, the last column gets combined into one CSV cell such as this: [Excel Finish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjkF7.jpg)

I'm thinking it can get there with the right combination of Index and Match functions, but I haven't gotten it to work yet.... any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

I currently have the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,C2=C1),"",D2&", 
"&INDEX(A2:D17,MATCH(A2,A2:A17,0)+1,4)&", 
"&INDEX(A2:D17,MATCH(A2,A2:A17,0)+2,4)&", 
"&INDEX(A2:D17,MATCH(A2,A2:A17,0)+3,4)&", 
"&INDEX(A2:D17,MATCH(A2,A2:A17,0)+5,4))
```

Which yields this ouput in Colum E: [Formula Output Column E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkVGZ.jpg)

As you can see, it either includes too many rows (Row 2 and 6 output) or too few (Row 8 output).  Hope this helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the array formula (means you have to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> altogether) you can use in your `CSV Output` column:

```
{=IF(OR(ROW(E1)=1,MAX(--($A$1:A1=A2)*--($B$1:B1=B2)*--($C$1:C1=C2)*ROW($A$1:A1))=0),D2,INDEX($E$1:E1,MAX(--($A$1:A1=A2)*--($B$1:B1=B2)*--($C$1:C1=C2)*ROW($A$1:A1)))&", "&D2)}
```

Here is the explanation but I also included a picture for your reference:

[image]

- `Column F`: This is to find the last matched row and this is also an array formula:

  `{=MAX(--($A$1:A2=A3)*--($B$1:B2=B3)*--($C$1:C2=C3)*ROW($A$1:A2))}`

  The `--` just easy to see when you evaluate formulas.  You can remove them if you want.
- `Column G`: This is to concatenate the prior outcome:

  `=IF(OR(ROW(G1)=1,F2=0),D2,INDEX($G$1:G1,F2)&", "&D2)`

Hope this helps.  Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Is this just showing all the values at the end? or is it removing the ones that aren't needed anywhere?

Comment: It will show as indicated in the picture so which will concatenate all the output together.  You will need to do what ChrisM showed you.  The benefit of using my formula will work for non-sequential order.  For example, if someone entered a 907 in row 15.  This formula will still work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two extra columns and type

```
=IF(AND(A2=A3,C2=C3),D2&","&E3,D2)
```

in cell E2 and

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,C2=C1),"",E2)
```

in cell F2 like in the following example

[image]

Then you will get the output for column CSV Output correct but in row F instead of row E, as below when you fill the formula to the bottom.

[image]